# Laravel Ignition 'edit' links contain extra 'open?url=file://' in subl:// links

Tags: laravel, homestead, laravel-6

I'm having trouble getting Laravel 6 Ignition's edit links to work with Sublime Text 3 on Windows through Homestead (I never got this working in Whoops either though).

--

1. I installed [subl protocol](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/subl%20protocol) through ST3 package control.
2. The following link successfully opens up the correct file in Sublime if I enter it in my browser's address bar and press enter (also confirmed it worked with a test.htm page I created with anchor links):

> subl://C:/Sites/laravel/server.php:11

3. The edit links currently generated by Ignition look like this:

> subl://open?url=file://c%3A%2FSites%2Flaravel%2Fapp%2FHttp%2FControllers%2FAccountController.php&line=396

4. My .env includes these:

.

```
IGNITION_EDITOR=sublime 
IGNITION_REMOTE_SITES_PATH=/home/vagrant/code/laravel
IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH=c:/Sites/laravel
```

5. My config/ignition.php file is unchanged, although I tried putting the same values above into their respective empty ''s in this file as well. No change.

--

So I'm wondering if I should either: A) somehow get Ignition to generate links in the 'subl://C:/Sites/laravel/file.php:123' format that I know works with the subl protocol package I have installed, or B) get my subl protocol package to work with the 'subl://open?url=file://etc%2Ffile.php&line=123' format that Ignition is generating.

Comment: Ignition hasn't worked very well for me either. Even with the additional package required for inline editing. Generally speaking, I preferred whoops. Still, it serves its purpose.

Comment: It appears the var I'm trying to change is actually in the Whoops package: https://github.com/filp/whoops/blob/master/src/Whoops/Handler/PrettyPageHandler.php#L103

Comment: ...as well as the Ignition compiled ignition.js: https://github.com/facade/ignition/blob/master/resources/compiled/ignition.js#L7

Comment: If I edit both of those, I can get it work.

in /vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/PrettyPageHandler.php:103, change to "sublime" => "subl://%file:%line",

...and in the vendor/face/ignition/resources/compiled/ignition.js:7, search for sublime and change to sublime:"subl://%path:%line

Obviously it's not a good idea to edit the vendor files directly, but I'm not sure yet how to override those appropriately instead of editing them. If anyone can fill in that gap, I'd appreciate it, otherwise I'll follow-up when I figure that out. At least it's working for now.

Answer (score 1):

Update (January 2022): I am not sure if the methods I am refering to existed two years ago, but now you don't have to edit the vendor files directly. The `PrettyPageHandler` in `Whoops\Handler` has two handy methods:

- [`#setEditor( $editor )`](https://github.com/filp/whoops/blob/a63e5e8f26ebbebf8ed3c5c691637325512eb0dc/src/Whoops/Handler/PrettyPageHandler.php#L462)
- [`#addEditor( $identifier, $resolver )`](https://github.com/filp/whoops/blob/a63e5e8f26ebbebf8ed3c5c691637325512eb0dc/src/Whoops/Handler/PrettyPageHandler.php#L485)

Either you can define a callback with `#setEditor( ... )` and define the wanted string there, or you overwrite the string pattern for SublimeText with `#addEditor( ... )`:

```php
# either ...
$run->setEditor(function ($file, $line) {
  return sprintf(
    'subl://%s:%d',
    $file,
    $line
  );
});

# ... or
$run->addEditor(
  'sublime',
  'subl://%file:%line'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using VS Code in a remote container using WSL and Docker.

Sorry if this doesn't answer OP's question exactly, but I found this answer trying to fix my issue.

Try updating your `.env` file to

```bash
# You can also set this in the GUI
IGNITION_EDITOR=vscode-remote

# Path inside your docker container to your application root
IGNITION_REMOTE_SITES_PATH=/var/www/html

# use "wsl={distro}/{application_root_in_wsl}
IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH=wsl+Ubuntu/home/angus/projects/laravel/
```

Tested and worked in Laravel 10.x.

I hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit Laravel Ignition [IgnitionConfig.php](https://github.com/spatie/ignition/blob/main/src/Config/IgnitionConfig.php#:%7E:text=%27sublime%27%20%3D%3E%20%5B,%5D) located at `"vendor\spatie\ignition\src\Config\IgnitionConfig.php"` **(line 153)**.

Subl Protocol URL

```
'sublime' => [
   'label' => 'Sublime',
   'url' => 'subl://%path:%line',
 ],
```

`%path` is the file path variable.
`%line` is the line variable.

**Tested on Laravel 9**.